# Target all the specific elements except the on clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Inside the loop in the function `thirdNavFunction`, I need to target all the `.third-nav` classes except the one clicked on and it needs to be done without jQuery, how do I do this?

```
var thirdNav = document.getElementsByClassName("third-nav");


for (var i = 0; i < thirdNav.length; i++){
    thirdNav[i].addEventListener("click", thirdNavFuntion);
}

function thirdNavFuntion() {

  for (i = 0; i < thirdNav.length; i++) {
    thirdNav[i].parentElement.className = "";
  }

  if (this.parentElement.className === "") {
    this.parentElement.className = "nav-sub-li-active";
  } else {
    this.parentElement.className = "";
  }
}
```

In the code here, I target all the `.third-nav` divs, but that doesn't work as intended, I need to exclude the one that is clicked. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: What is error you are getting here?

Comment: There is no error, it's just not the intended outcome, but the answer provided solved my issue perfectly. I'll mark it as solved as soon as it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Convert `thirdNav` to array using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- Filter out the clicked element using the [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.
- Call the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method to change the class name of all parent elements.

```
function thirdNavFuntion() {
  const elements = Array.from(thirdNav).filter(el => el !== this)
  elements.forEach(el => el.parentElement.className = "")
}
```